# I want to merge 3 queries into 1 query in SQL

Tags: sql, join

I have the data in the below schema structure:

[schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF0Af.png)

I want to make one query with these queries

query 1

```
SELECT course.cname, count(*) as 'numberOfActivites'
from activity 
join course on course.cid = activity.cid
group by course.cname
```

query 2

```
SELECT  course.cname, count(*) as 'numberOfStud'
from course 
join enrolledstd on course.cid = enrolledstd.cid
join student on student.studentid = enrolledstd.studentid
GROUP by course.cname
```

query 3

```
SELECT course.cname, avg(score.score) as 'averageScore'
from course 
join activity on activity.cid = course.cid
join score on score.acid = activity.acid
group by course.cname
```

so it looks like this

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3753i.png)

help me please :D

tried everything but nothing worked :(

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT course.cname, count(*) as 'numberOfActivities', count(DISTINCT enrolledstd.studentid) as 'numberOfStudents', avg(score.score) as 'averageScore'
FROM course
LEFT JOIN activity ON activity.cid = course.cid
LEFT JOIN score ON score.acid = activity.acid
LEFT JOIN enrolledstd ON course.cid = enrolledstd.cid
GROUP BY course.cname
```

Answer (score 0):

you may need to share what you have tried.

but the below should work:

```
SELECT course.cname, count(DISTINCT ctivity.cid) as 'numberOfActivities',count(DISTINCT enrolledstd.studentid) as 'numberOfStudents',avg(score.score) as 'averageScore'
FROM course
LEFT JOIN activity ON activity.cid = course.cid
LEFT JOIN score ON score.acid = activity.acid
LEFT JOIN enrolledstd ON course.cid = enrolledstd.cid
GROUP BY course.cname
```